# wont boot, freezes at purple screen, cant use terminal to fix at all. tried it already

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, permissions, external-hdd

installed ubuntu on a External HDD, 
wont boot

first time installation ran after installing it to the HDD from windows and restarted.

but it wont boot after that, it freezes at a purple screen.

i tried to do those update commands in Terminal but i cannot for the life of me get them to work, it keeps saying i dont either have permission to do it, or have permission to write to disk. 
additionally ive tried to put it in safe GFX mode, ive tried turning networking on but it fails to boot the networking modem.

Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: same options as the link I gave

Comment: you installed from windows? that's not recommended

Comment: i used the program included on the CD, i dont have any CD's to burn it physically onto, and it wont let me do it from a USB, so i had to run the windows installer for it.

Comment: if you need permission you should use sudo but be carefull

Comment: buy some dvds and try that way

Comment: i did and it said i cant write to disk

Comment: you just said you don't have any disks to burn to

Comment: i mean the SUDO thing u suggested

Comment: ubuntu is case sensitive, don't use caps

Comment: i didnt i did
sudo apt-get update (or however they worded it) and it said i dont have permission.

Comment: i'd be careful running those commands as they are probably not for ubuntu installed through windows. again, that method is not recommended. It would be best just to wait until you have some blank disks to work with so you can do  it right.

Comment: is there a version i can get that boots like a live CD that is 14.0.4 LTS desktop that i can run from a external hdd or flashdrive?

Comment: cuz i tried to find one on the download page of the ubuntu site and cannot find it at all

Comment: you can install it to USB but you said the box won't let you so....

Comment: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

Comment: thx ill try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using WUBI is not recommended and it is recommended you install using the CD.**

if you installed ubuntu to an external hdd, you probably just need to go into bios and make the external drive the first on the  boot order or select boot menu during startup and select the hdd from there

it won't boot because the bootloader (grub) is most likely installed to the hdd instead of the main hard drive so it is not running when you boot. choosing the external hdd as a boot option or setting it first on the bootloader list in bios will fix this problem.

Comment: ok ill try it, thx

Comment: which version of ubuntu appears? the one installed on the external device or the one installed using windows?

Comment: @Rcj8993 most computers let you press one of the F buttons to access a boot menu during startup.

Comment: it worked.i just had to install it through the cd and not windows.

Comment: @mchid: he was using wubi...  Could you please [edit] your answer and strongly suggest no one uses wubi any more and use a CD/DVD/USB install???  Please???  (I'll come back and upvote if you leave a comment @ Fabby)  **;-)**